# Is there any way to remove overflow from the bottom of a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Is there any way to remove overflow: hidden from the top and right part of the box? I don't want dog's ear and nose clipped at the end of animation. At 60%,100% position the dog's nose and ear should not be clipped but his body at the bottom and left should be clipped so that it looks like he put his head through the hole. I thought of using clip-path I cannot find a shape to do it. Is there any css property or technique to do this? Please help.

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dog {
  width: 115%;
  height: 115%;
  animation: dogPeeking 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes dogPeeking {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -10%) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  60%,100% {
    transform: translate(10%, -10%) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddq2p90tz/image/upload/v1662628751/dog_dr7izv.png" alt="dog" class="dog" />
</div>
```

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Do you have a final image to show us?

Comment: You would need a clip path like the 4th example in this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path but with the semi circle to the left - not sure how to do that though as my path knowledge isn't good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try an approach for multiple layers with the half-circles. The left circle will be the main layer (which you're using right now), and the right circle will be under the dog layer.

```css
.box {
  width: 550px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 250px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 250px;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-right-radius: 250px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 250px;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.dog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  animation: dogPeeking 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes dogPeeking {
  0% {
transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  60%,100% {
transform: translate(0, 0) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddq2p90tz/image/upload/v1662628751/dog_dr7izv.png" alt="dog" class="dog"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Really cool technique, did you learn it somewhere or did it come with experience?

Comment: It's just my experience with a little creativity. Hopefully, This solution is helpful to you :D @void__

Comment: That's fantastic; hopefully I'll reach your level one day. Thank you once more! I was really struggling with this until you came along :)

Comment: I just modified my code to have a solution with less code, you can check it out again, @void__

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some positioning to your dog class like this,

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 115%;
  height: 115%;
  animation: dogPeeking 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
```